# How to sync asset libraries

Tags: 2013

I am using OneDrive with SharePoint 2013. I am able to sync document libraries and the like to the drive no problem. But it seems Asset Library App and Image Libraries are not sync-able. Does anyone know why? Or if there is an alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  The OneDrive sync application only looks for libraries with the BaseTemplate of 101 (DocumentLibrary).  Any other types of libraries will not show up.

Rather than use the Asset Library type when creating the library, you could create a Document Library and then make it into your pictures library.